# Docker. Could not find a JVM

Tags: docker

При выполнении команды `build`, получаю следующую ошибку:

> Could not find a JVM. Make sure either JAVA_HOME is set correctly in
>   your environment, AS_JAVA is set correctly in the config/asenv file
>   ,or java-home is set correctly in the domain.xml configuration.

Я понимаю что стоит установить `JVM` и проставить переменные окружения, но как это сделать?

Comment: что именно вы билдите и какое изображение используете в качестве основного?

Comment: @Etki reap/docker-glassfish3

Comment: Внутри уже есть JVM 7, которая верно находится по `java`. На какой команде валится билд?

Comment: @Etki билд валится на команде  RUN /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy /var/file.war

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, полный докерфайл. У меня вызывается без проблем.

Comment: @Etki к сожалению выложить файл не могу, он находится на другом компьютере и в данный момент он не под руками..но в докерфайле ничего интересного (FROM,ENV,EXPOSE,RUN)..но дело в том что на основе даного образа я создаю другой и работаю с ним (возможно в этом проблема?).

Comment: Боюсь, я просто не могу сказать без подробностей. Возможно, вы переопределили AS_JAVA в asenv, возможно, что-то еще, но ваша инструкция не может найти бинарник джавы. btw, есть вероятность, что это вообще должно выполняться уже после запуска контейнера.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33909/discussion-between-andrey-ku-and-etki).